# execute function automatically in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want this function to execute automatically, but not working.

```
    $scope.checkdate = function(){
    $scope.checked = 0;
    $scope.unchecked = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.inventories.length; i++) {
        if($scope.inventories[i].modified === $scope.time){
            $scope.checked = $scope.checked + 1;
        }else if($scope.time2 !== $scope.time){
            $scope.unchecked = $scope.unchecked + 1;
        }
    }
};
$scope.checkdate();
```

And my template looks like this:

```
<ul ng-init="checkdate()">
        <li><input type="checkbox" /> Checked {{checked}}</li> 
        <li><input type="checkbox" /> Unchecked {{unchecked}}</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" />   All</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you can remove the ng-init="checkdate()" since it's already called inside the controller. It does not answer the question though

Comment: Is your controller that is associated with your the above $scope being instantiated? Do you know that `$scope.inventories.length` is greater than 0? Though your example seems a bit incomplete, on the surface what you are trying to do should work.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, from [Angular's documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) about `ng-init`:

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat

So you shouldn't be using it in your example.

Second of all, your init function should not be attached to `$scope` because there is no need for it. It should be a private function of a controller.

Third of all, we cannot see the definition of your controller. It may very well be that you haven't created one and thus - Angular won't care about the rest of the code.

Fifth of all, you would get a response in no time if you would have created a JS Fiddle with an example :)

Regardless, your code should look something like this (boilerplate). Should help you out.

HTML template:

```
<ul ng-controller="MyController">
        <li><input type="checkbox" /> Checked {{checked}}</li> 
        <li><input type="checkbox" /> Unchecked {{unchecked}}</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" />   All</li>
</ul>
```

`MyController.js`:

```
function MyController() {
    $scope.checked = 0;
    $scope.unchecked = 0;

    // Define what needs to be done during initialization below.
    function init() {
       // I haven't checked your code but there are some uninitialized variables in there like $scope.inventories....
       for(var i = 0; i < $scope.inventories.length; i++) {
           if ($scope.inventories[i].modified === $scope.time){
               $scope.checked = $scope.checked + 1;
           } else if ($scope.time2 !== $scope.time){
               $scope.unchecked = $scope.unchecked + 1;
           }
       }
    }

    init(); // Call your private init function here.
}
```

Comment: +1 `ng-init` may have been better named as something like `ng-repeat-init` or whatever. It seems everyone wants to mis-use it, despite the good intentions of the documentation :)

Comment: Yeah, I am using it extensively for bad purposes :D This is partially because it wasn't described properly with the older version of the documentation.